# submatrix of a given size with maximum frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $I\subset \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and let $|I|$ denote its cardinality. Now given  a Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbf{C}^{n\times n}$. I am interested in finding the subset $I$ that maximizes the following problem
\begin{align*}
\max_{I: |I|\le s} \|\mathbf{A}_{II}\|_F.
\end{align*}
Here $\mathbf{A}_{II}$ means the submatrix which picks columns and rows according to $I$. Stated differently I am interested in finding a submatrix of $\mathbf{A}$ of size $s\times s$ which has the largest Frobenius norm. Is there a simple tractable algorithm to do this. Please note that if I was asking for the Spectral norm instead of the Frobenius norm this would be an instance of sparse PCA and would be intractable in its most general form.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this problem is NP-Hard. Here's the argument.

Let $b_{ij} := |a_{ij}|^2$. Then, your problem is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
   \max_x\quad \sum\nolimits_{ij} b_{ij}x_ix_j,\qquad x^T1=s,\ x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace^n,
\end{equation*}
where $x$ is an indicator vector telling which rows/cols are to be selected.

From this formulation it is obvious that a brute-force method that works in time $\binom{n}{s}$ suffices to solve this problem.

Since $B=[b_{ij}] \ge 0$ (and symmetric), we can view $B$ as a weighted undirected graph. We can reduce the problem of finding a maximum clique to the above optimization problem (solution arrived at in discussion with S. Jegelka).

1. Suppose the above problem is solvable in polytime for any $s$
2. For a given weighted (with nonnegative weights) undirected graph, represent it via matrix $B$
3. For $s=1,\ldots,n$ we solve the above problem, and test (in polytime) if any of the solutions is a clique (i.e., the submatrix $B_{I,I}$ is dense), and pick the largest such solution.

If step $3$ is polytime, then we can solve max-clique in polytime, which proves that your original problem is NP-Hard.